# Почему нельзя изменить поле структуры, даже если оно является сеттером? С#

Tags: c#

Допустим следующую ситуацию:

```
struct MyStruct {
  public SomeClass? someObject;
  public SomeClass? SomeObject { get => someObject; set => someObject= value;}
  public void SetObject(SomeClass someObject) => this.someObject = someObject;
}
```

Если мы получаем структуру например с помощью get реализовав this[] (например простейшая реализация: `MyStruct this[int i]{get => arr[i]; set => arr[i] = value;}`), то мы по очевидным причинам не можем изменить `MyStruct.someObject`. Однако метод `MyStruct.SetObject(obj)` не вызывает ошибки, чего нельзя сказать про `MyStruct.SomeObject = obj`, хотя по сути они выполняют идентичный код. Можете прояснить, почему setter не работает, а метод работает?

И в целом работая с массивом (`MyStruct[] array`) мы можем изменять поля структуры (`array[0].someObject = ...`). Как мне можно реализовать подобный функционал в объекте?

EDIT: Прикрепляю примерный код по просьбе:

```
class CellData {public int param;} // Его можно переопределять

struct CellContainer{
  /* тут всякие другие поля */
  public CellData? cellData;
  public CellData? CellData {get => cellData; set => cellData = value;}
  public void SetCellData(CellData? cellData) => this.cellData = cellData;
}

class Grid{
  CellContainer[,] grid;
  public CellContainer this[Vector2 pos]
  {
    get => grid[pos.x, pos.y]; 
    set => grid[pos.x, pos.y] = value;
  }
}

Grid grid = …;
grid[pos].cellData = …; // Не работает
grid[pos].CellData = …; // Тоже не работает
grid[pos].SetCellData(…); // Не вызывает ошибок
```

---

Хотя по идее `SetObject` не должен изменять оригинальный объект, а только его копию в... а где она хранится вообще если мы её не сохраняем в стеке

Comment: "по очевидным причинам не можем изменить" - можем. Какая у вас ошибка появляется? О чём вообще вопрос?

Comment: @Aarnihauta Извиняюсь, массив не подойдёт, более хорошим примером будет кастомный массив с прописанными get и set для this[i], из за чего структуру и нельзя изменить, так как возвращается не ссылка на объект, а сам объект (участок памяти с данными структуры)

Comment: Сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: @Aarnihauta отредактировал вопрос, прошу прощения за неточную формулировку и ошибки

Comment: Сделайте нормальный минимально воспроизводимый код который относится непосредственно к вопросу

Comment: @Aarnihauta Готово

Comment: Cтруктуры являются значимыми типами данных, когда вы обращаетесь к полю структуры вы на самом деле работаете с копией этой структуры, а не с оригинальным экземпляром.
Изменения внесенные в поля структуры не будут видны снаружи, потому что вы работаете с копией. Структуры передаются по значению, а не по ссылке, как классы.

Метод же работает потому что они вызываются на конкретном экземпляре.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct

Comment: @air, т. е. как я понял работаю я с копией структуры на вершине стека полученного в результате определённого метода, из за чего метод будет воздействовать на клон структуры, а не на оригинал, из за чего как раз таки нельзя вызвать setter, ведь по стандарту он нужен только для изменения значения, что не имеет смысла в копии, ведь более это значение нигде не используется, верно?
Ладно, это вроде понятно, но как я могу сделать изменение структуры, подобно тому, как это работает с массивами?

Comment: Хранить массив классов как по мне дорого, ведь будет выделяться огромная куча ненужных маленьких объектов в куче...

Comment: Через структуры никак, только через классы, только они позволяют менять их поля напрямую.

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей что-то ваш "воспроизводимый" пример содержал кучу синтаксических ошибок

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут всё дело в том, что структуры передаются по значению.

Смотрите, когда вы обращаетесь к свойству типа структуры, "за кадром" происходит вот это:

```cs
var temp0 = grid[pos];
temp0.cellData = …;

var temp1 = grid[pos];
temp1.CellData = …;

var temp2 = grid[pos];
temp2.SetCellData(…);
```

То есть сначала структура копируется, а потом у этой копии вы пытаетесь что-то изменить.

Поскольку эта операция совершенно бессмысленна, компилятор вам и не даёт делать прямые присвоения полям и свойствам. А вот вызов метода компилятор делать разрешает - поскольку не знает что именно этот метод делает.

Как обойти эту проблему? Ну, есть два варианта. Для начала, можно отказаться от структуры и сделать ваш CellContainer классом.

Кроме того, в современных версиях языка можно возвращать ссылку на структуру:

```cs
class Grid{
  CellContainer[,] grid;
  public ref CellContainer this[Vector2 pos]
  {
    get => ref grid[pos.x, pos.y]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, особенно про ref! не знал про такую фишку языка, даже не подумал, уже хотел начать unsafe использовать)